# Getting a list of multiple elements with same class name using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

There's a website I want to scrape that has numerous divs with the same class name.

For example, let's say this class name is `article-container`
There are 12 divs holding this class name in the site. I tried to retrieve them all like this:

```
articles = response.css('[class^="article-container]')
```

And then call them individually using something like:

```
print(article[2])
```

But that didn't work. What's the best approach to solve this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by “But that didn't work”? Did you get an exception? Did you get `None`? Did you get a value that was unexpected? If so, what did you expect? What was the input?

Comment: I notice you're missing a closing `"` in your response.css statement.

Answer (score 0):

get the div first, by name, this will render a list type data structure

```
articles = response.css('div.name')
```

you can then loop through this list with

```
for article in articles:
    article.css('.article-container::text').extract
```

which also means you should be able to use indexes on the list and also get and extract the text of the class if you so desire with the

> .extract() function. exclude it if you do not want to extract